# Is the .NET Reflector unable to reflect over the null-coalescing operator correctly?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, .net-reflector, null-coalescing

I wrote this piece of code:

```
private Queue<int> EnsureQueue()
{
    return _queue ?? (_queue = new Queue<int>(10));
}
```

and the reflector gives me:

```
private Queue<int> EnsureQueue()
{
    if (this._queue == null)
    {
    }
    return (this._queue = new Queue<int>(10));
}
```

Obviously, this is not what the original code says. The line `(this._queue = new Queue<int>(10));` will alway return a `new Queue<int>(10)` instead of `_queue` when it is not `null`.

Is this a bug in the `.NET Reflector` or am I missing something? The program seems to behave correctly...

**EDIT**
 -> See my answer

Comment: The ?? operator is syntactic sugar, you are seeing what the compiler is translating it into.

Comment: @RonBeyer But the output is not correct, is it?

Comment: Can you post the raw IL? It would probably be a lot clearer if you saw what the reflector was trying to translate from. Usually I find that JetBrains DotPeek is a little more accurate than Redgate's, and I'm opposed to using Redgate after they "promised" to keep Reflector free, then started charging outrageously for it. DotPeek is free.

Comment: ILSpy is a free Reflector clone that is pretty awesome. There's even a port of the Reflexil plugin for it to let you edit the IL of the assembly.

Comment: If compiled ?? is indistinguishable from if != null return then I guess there is nothing decompilers can do.

Comment: I dont understand, can you tell me the difference between `return _queue ?? (_queue = new Queue<int>(10));` and `return (this._queue = new Queue<int>(10));`. i think the null-coalescing is redundant here. because both will set the `_queue` and will return it as result

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The part after `??` will only execute if the part before is `null`.

Comment: Which version of .NET / Visual Studio / Compiler, and can you post a complete program that has this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what my copy of Reflector makes of this method:

```
private Queue<int> EnsureQueue()
{
    return (this._queue ?? (this._queue = new Queue<int>(10)));
}
```

Looks pretty darn good to me.  Version 8.5.0.179, be sure to update yours.

Comment: I actually have the same version: 8.5.0.179 (Trial `???!!!` (I hope this is not the source of the problem))

Comment: That's very unlikely.  Maybe you ought to post a better snippet, I had to guess at the _queue variable.

Comment: Are there any options for Reflector, like C# version, compiler version, how to decompile certain constructs etc.?